# Flutter - How can I prevent Gestures on Child from bubbling up Widget Tree

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture

My app uses Gestures to change panes. In one of these panes I have a `flutter_map` widget in a Container.

I've been looking for a way to prevent all gestures in the Container from bubbling up the WidgetTree.

I've tried wrapping the container in a GestureDetector and overriding the target gestures or setting it's behavior to all available options, to no avail.

I've tried wrapping it into Absorb- and IgnorePointers, and that failed as well.